# Unable to receive messages by read() from device in serial communication by Linux & C++

Tags: c++, linux, serial-communication

I'm trying to communicate with a motor device via serial communication(RS485) by Ubuntu18 & C++.

I wrote this C++ code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>

int main(){
  char *dev = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
  int fd = 0;
  char message[3];
  char reply[1024];

  struct termios oldtio, newtio;
  memset(&oldtio, 0, sizeof(oldtio));
  memset(&newtio, 0, sizeof(newtio));


  //Open COM Port;
  fd = open(dev, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
  if(fd < 0){
    std::cout << "COM Port Error" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }
  tcgetattr(fd, &oldtio);

  //Serial Settings
  cfsetispeed(&newtio, B115200);
  cfsetospeed(&newtio, B115200);

  newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR;

  newtio.c_cflag |= CS8;
  newtio.c_cflag |= CREAD;
  newtio.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;

  newtio.c_lflag = ICANON;


  tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &newtio);

  //Set Message(This is not real one because it will be too long)
  messages[0] = char(0x02);
  messages[1] = char(0x32);
  messages[2] = char(0x03);

  //Send Message
  write(fd, message, 3);

  //Receive Message
  unsigned int length = 0;
  length = read(fd, reply, 1024);
  std::cout << reply << std::endl;

  //Close Serial Port
  tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &oldtio);
  close(fd);
}
```

・I added `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr` (24/09/2021)
・modified `strlen(message)` to just `3`

(This serial communication is done by ASCII and it starts with STX(0x02), ends with ETX(0x03).)

I could send a message correctly. I verified this by checking a motor working.
But I couldn't receive the message from the device that automatically replys message.
In detail, the process stops at `length = read(fd, reply, 1024)` and won't move on next line.

I verified the TxD and RxD lamp blinks correctly so the reply message must be send. And I could received reply message by pySerial in Python.

Is there any mistakes in this code for serial communication ?

Comment: I think you need to get and set the settings of the serial port using `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr` to actiually use the communication speed and settings. Otherwise the port will use default settings (or old settings) that probably don't match the connected device.

Comment: @Bodo Thank you for your advice. I modified my code by adding ```tcgetattr``` and ```tcsetattr```. But read() still won't receive any messages.

Comment: Try `length = read(fd, reply, 1)` and see if you get something.

Comment: you probably.want read in a loop reading 1 byte at a time. read 1024 isnt going to return because its going to wair for 1024 bytes

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. @camelcc
I tried ```length = read(fd, reply, 1)``` but I couldn't receive any messages.

Comment: The `strlen` call is wrong. The `strlen` function is exclusively for use on strings. You can't use it on arbitrary arrays of data. Similarly your `std::cout << reply << std::endl`; is also wrong. How could it possibly know how many bytes of output to write?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  May I take it that ```strlen()``` and ```std::cout << reply << std::endl``` seem to work well but as a matter of fact their behaviors are undifined?
Either way I modified them.

Comment: You are using `newtio` to set the flags. The setting read from the device is in `oldtio`, use it to set the flags and call `tcsetattr`.

Comment: @FaisalM I fixed my code ```tcgetattr(fd, &oldtio)``` to ```tcgetattr(fd, &newtio)``` so that I can set additional setting to old one.But it works same as before.

Comment: Don't forget to check the system clock of the device. Many times with MCU's a default clock for the device is too slow to handle both send and receive over the UART. (example on the TI MSP432 with a default clock of 3MHz, simo communication fails due to processor saturation, a setting of 12MHz works just fine). Something to check on the device side.

Comment: Check the return value of all functions. Many functions return 0 or the number of bytes/elements processed on success and <0 on errors . In case of an error, the correct reaction may depend on the value of `errno`. For testing you can simply display the error using e.g. `perror( "write(message)" );`. It doesn't make sense to get the structure with `tcgetattr` and not use the value. Either get the structure, modify it and set it or fully initialize a new structure and set it. In the latter case you must make sure to set all required values. (I don't know what all is essential.)